# Change the UpDown controls on NumericUpDown in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a NumericUpDown control where I need to make the UpDown controls bigger for touch screen. Can someone help me with this problem?

Here is my XAML:

```
<xctk1:NumericUpDown Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" 
                             Minimum="0" Maximum="24" Value="0" 
                             Name="hoursUpDown" Height="100" Width="200" 
                             FontSize="70" Margin="22,37,10,33" Background="#FFB8B6B6" 
                             BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
            
</xctk1:NumericUpDown>
```

Comment: We could if you would provide us information, which third party library you are using for the control. In general you should be able to override the Template of the control in order to archive what you desire

Comment: I'm using Extended.Wpf.Toolkit and my assembly reference (schema) is: xmlns:xctk1="http://schemas.talex-soft.com/2010/xaml/presentation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never heard of that lib for controls, but it seems simplest solution would be override the Style of the control. To do that you can add following code to your App.xaml:

```
 <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBrush" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="1.0"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>

                <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBorderBrush" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#444" Offset="1.0"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>

                <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HoverBrush" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#AAA" Offset="1.0"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>

                <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PressedBrush" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#BBB" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="0.1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="0.9"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="1.0"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>

                <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PressedBorderBrush" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#444" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#888" Offset="1.0"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>

                <!-- NumericUpDown -->
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type talex:NumericUpDown}">
                    <Style.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}" x:Key="IncreaseButton" BasedOn="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="15" />
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Border Name="Border" BorderThickness="25" BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}" CornerRadius="0 1 0 0" Margin="0" Padding="0" Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}"></Border>
                                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="ContentPresenter" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplateSelector}"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HoverBrush}"/>
                                            </Trigger>

                                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PressedBrush}"/>
                                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PressedBorderBrush}"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>

                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}" x:Key="DecreaseButton" BasedOn="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="15" />
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Border Name="Border" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}" CornerRadius="0 0 1 0" Margin="0" Padding="0" Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}"></Border>
                                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="ContentPresenter" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplateSelector}"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HoverBrush}"/>
                                            </Trigger>

                                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PressedBrush}"/>
                                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PressedBorderBrush}"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </Style.Resources>

                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ffffffff" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#ff848484"/>

                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type talex:NumericUpDown}">
                                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <TextBox Name="textbox" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="Transparent" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />

                                    <RepeatButton Margin="0" Padding="0" Command="{x:Static talex:NumericUpDown.IncreaseCommand}"
                            Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Focusable="False" Style="{StaticResource IncreaseButton}">
                                        <Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Width="5" Height="3" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="{x:Null}" Data="M0,1L1,0 2,1z"/>
                                    </RepeatButton>

                                    <RepeatButton Margin="0" Padding="0" Command="{x:Static talex:NumericUpDown.DecreaseCommand}"
                            Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Focusable="False" Style="{StaticResource DecreaseButton}">
                                        <Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Width="5" Height="3" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="{x:Null}" Data="M0,0L2,0 1,1z"/>
                                    </RepeatButton>

                                    <Border CornerRadius="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>

                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

Here you can see the defined style for the RepeatButtons, where you can change the size and look of the side buttons in you control. For example I have set BorderThickness to 25 (which will increase the size of the buttons as you wanted)

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/382676/… - (the accepted answer on this question) this works perfectly for me and it's actually what we need, thank you very much for your help.